# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /hermes/bosnaweb15a/b1372/ipg.thestephaniestorecom/mysql.php on line 39

Tags: php, mysql

need php help.  getting the error message when attempting to connect to mysql database.. below is my source code around line 39 that its complaining about:

```
    // checks username does not exist
    public function checkUsername($username) {
         $sql = "SELECT username FROM Registration WHERE username = '$username'";
         $this->result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($this->result <= 0) {
              return false;
         }     
         return true;
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound 
parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prep
ared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examp
les.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket on the end of the file, which closes the function. You are also missing one here: `if (mysqli_num_rows($this->result <= 0) {`

Change your code to this:

```
public function checkUsername($username) {
         $sql = "SELECT username FROM Registration WHERE username = '$username'";
         $this->result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($this->result ) <= 0 ) {
              return false;
         }     
         return true;

}
```

Use a syntax checker like this one next time: https://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: I've corrected it in my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Was tunnel visioned by my debugger. I see what you mean, and have corrected it.